# jQuery on page load sequential loading of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'd like to know how this effect (http://www.getflow.com/) is achieved.

I'm guessing that it's using jQuery to sequentially change the opacity of each element.

Could anyone post a quick snippet of js to make this happen (load in each image, one every 3 seconds)

http://jsfiddle.net/5hdcz/2/

Thanks!

Comment: Like this? I hope you get the idea: http://jsfiddle.net/5hdcz/3/.

Comment: Probably want to post that as an answer. If you wanted to keep this strictly in jQuery you could use the `.animate()` function using the callback to cue up the next image.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fadeIn callback functions:

```
$('#img1').fadeIn('slow', function() {

    $('#img2').fadeIn('slow', function() {

         // and so on...

    });

});
```